# import wx not working in uncompiled scripts

Tags: wxpython

I have installed Python 2.7.5 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 on my new Windows 7 machine, and the 'import wx' statement doesn't work when I try to run the containing .py script directly from the Windows command prompt or from the Windows explorer.  (It does work in the compiled .pyc file, or if I run the script from the interactive interpreter using import, or using the python command at the Windows command prompt.)

The script looks like this:

```
import wx
print wx.version()
raw_input("Test runs OK - hit Enter to exit")
```

In the failure case, the output looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\First Python Project\src\root\nested\test.py", line 2, in ?
    print wx.version()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'

I suspect this has something to do with my wxPython installation, because 'import os' works fine however I run the script.

Thanks for any help.  I've looked but can't find this question elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you may have named one of your scripts "wx.py" in C:\First Python Project\src\root\nested. If so, you are shadowing wxPython itself. Python will import you wx.py because it's first on the path and it won't even try to import the right one. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't done that. If I had, I doubt that the script would work when compiled or run from the Python prompt.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? That would also cause this.

Comment: Bingo! - Obvious when I think about it, thanks for that.  Just had to do some poking in the registry to correct the default interpreter path (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python\shell\Open\command), as removing the old interpreter path from PATH made no difference.  This is on Win 7 - Several other solutions to this problem (changing the default interpreter) quoted different registry key paths, but I just had to search through the registry to find the right one.

Comment: Usually I can fix this sort of thing by going into Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs and then do a repair on the Python version I want to be default